# Amazon Fire TV stick adbLink Device Unauthorised

Tags: android-device-manager, amazon-fire-tv

When following the tutorial to disable the annoying 20 minute Amazon Stick sleep timer and using the method that changes the sleep time value in the core shell, you might not be able to connect to the amazon stick using adbLink with the error: Device unauthorised press refresh or see help.”

The tutorials that you will find will be completely useless, they will be a horrible video of the developer pressing the refresh ADB button, and a badly written developer tutorial that tells you to delete some files somewhere on some device.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. I strongly recommend to edit your question to improve it and especially to make it more clear what your actual question is. Also note that a good question should link to the external tutorial it refers to.

Comment: @Robert my question is the tutorial because I found the solution, other suggested fixes on the internet are a joke

Comment: If you want write a tutorial first create the question without the solution and afterwards answer your own question with the solution. Anyway I don't see where your post contains helpful information. Please make it more clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is easily resolved by connecting the amazon stick to the correct primary WiFi channel, usually that is 2.4GHz channel by default. If your stick is connected to the 5GHz channel of your network it might not be discoverable by the adbLink.

Answer (score 0):

I found toggling the developer mode off then back on on the Fire Stick worked for me.