# ADB | How do I Authorise Amazon FireTV Stick via. USB? - to run shell script on boot

Tags: adb, linux, amazon-fire-tv

Goal: Follow this [tutorial](https://www.aftvnews.com/how-to-automatically-run-shell-script-files-at-boot-on-a-rooted-amazon-fire-tv-or-fire-tv-stick/#delete), to run a shell script on boot.

Despite following the tutorial and trying various solutions, I am still unable to authorise the ADB connection. I'd greatly appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Linux:

```
(base) me@laptop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

```
(base) danielbell@laptop:~$ curl ifconfig.me
109.144.211.17
```

FireTV Stick is in Developer Mode and I've both turned `OFF` and `ON` and restarted several times:

- ADB Debugging
- Apps from Unknown Sources

In 'My Fire TV' -> 'Network':

- 'IP Address:' `100.120.226.156`
- 'DNS:' `192.168.22.22`

```
(base) me@laptop:~$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 28.0.2-debian
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb

(base) me@laptop:~$ adb kill-server
(base) me@laptop:~$ adb start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully

(base) me@laptop:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached
G070L81693920FDB    unauthorized

(base) me@laptop:~$ adb connect 100.120.226.156
missing port in specification: tcp:100.120.226.156
(base) me@laptop:~$ adb connect 100.120.226.156:5555
failed to connect to '100.120.226.156:5555': Connection timed out

(base) me@laptop:~$ adb connect 192.168.22.22
missing port in specification: tcp:192.168.22.22
(base) me@laptop:~$ adb connect 192.168.22.22:5555
failed to connect to '192.168.22.22:5555': Connection timed out
```

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. From the output of `adb devices`, looks like a device is already connected, is that the FireTV stick?

Comment: Yes; the device mentioned in `adb devices` is the FireTV Stick. I kinda doubt that it is connected, given that whenever I run either of the `adb connect` commands there's a different failure.

Comment: Hmm, I was actually curious why it's listed on `adb devices` then. Was it connected using USB cable instead (I don't know if it's possible or not)?

Comment: Yes; it's connected via. USB cable

Comment: Did you see [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219855/131553) to make adb devices authorised? I saw you are connected on USB but just may help

Comment: The tutorial requires using `adb shell`. That needs your Android device to be in Developer mode, which you've done, and requires you to use its screen to accept the debugging key when it's connected to your computer. Is it offering that? Have you ever used adb shell on any other Android device?